# How to unsubscribe / Opt out MobileConnect using SSJS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, mobileconnect

So far I found only APIs, is there a more simple code oriented way for that?
Like there is to Emails with:

```
var subObj = Subscriber.init(subkey);
var status = subObj.Unsubscribe();
```

Comment: API are your only option

Answer (score 1):

There is an unofficial trick way to do this with just SSJS.

Depending on whether you are asking about global MobileConnect status or keyword OptIn you need to leverage legacy `_MobileAddress` or `_MobileSubscription` Data View and update it using any Data Extension updating SSJS.

For example Init then `mobileAddress.Rows.Update()` - I shared an example with phone change on [my SFMC Docs page](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/ssjs/ssjs-snippet-mobileconnect-phone-change#solution), but it's the same approach for Subscription.

Remember that only those two legacy views can be modified this way - new ones are protected. But if you change the legacy ones, the new ones will be updated too.